# How can I skip validations of superclass in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, oop, ruby-on-rails-4

I have pretty big RoR app.
There is superclass named User.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, presence: true
end
```

Also I have class Client which inherited by User

```
class Client < User
with_options(on: [:personal_info]) do |pi|
  pi.validates :first_name,
               :last_name,
               :email,
               :mobile_phone,
               :landline_phone,
               presence: true
  pi.validates :primary_email,
               email_format: {
                 message: "doesn't look like an email address"
               }
end
end
```

When I create Client's object I got 2 errors that "Email can't be blank."
How can I disable or skip validates of superclass??
Remove validations in superclass is impossible.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3312055/3923525

Comment: Have you tried `validates :email, presence: false` in your Client class?

Comment: Wouldn't that validate the *absence* of the email, instead of just skipping the validation?