# Override validation in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have a spree [model](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/address.rb) that has the following validations:

```
with_options presence: true do
  validates :firstname, :lastname, :address1, :city, :country
  validates :zipcode, if: :require_zipcode?
  validates :phone, if: :require_phone?
end
```

I would like to remove the city and/or country from presence validation. In my `address_decorator` I wrote this:

```
Spree::Address.class_eval do

  with_options presence: true do
    validates :firstname, :lastname, :address1
    validates :zipcode, if: :require_zipcode?
    validates :phone, if: :require_phone?
  end
......
```

But this didn't remove city or country. Both are still demanded in order to create new record.

What am I missing?

Comment: This is works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24793039/5598574

Answer (score 0):

When you add "with_options" you are not removing the previous validations, you are just adding more.

So, there is to remove the validations for :city and :country

Not checked myself, but I´ve seen something similar to:

```
.class_eval do
  _validators.reject{ |key, _| key == :field }

  _validate_callbacks.reject do |callback|
    callback.raw_filter.attributes == [:field]
  end
```

where :field is :city and :country

Comment: Thanks but I get error: undefined method attributes. On the other hand this approach helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24793039/5598574